# Use of $/ in perl

Tags: perl

I have seen many examples over Internet using `$/` in perl over `split` but I couldn't understand the use.

Can any of you please explain how we use `$/` over `split` in Perl?

Comment: Could you post an example of exactly what you don't understand? The documentation (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) is pretty clear.

Answer (score 14):

If you use `readline $filehandle` (or `<$filehandle>`) in scalar context, it will return the remainder of the unread part of the file up to and including the next occurrence of the string in `$/`. By default this is set to a newline, so the next line of the file is returned.

```
my $line = <$filehandle>
```

and

```
while (<$filehandle>) { ... }
```

both impose scalar context, so the variable is set to the next line of the file, and the loop executes with one line of the file at a time in the `$_` variable.

Changing the value of `$/` can sometimes be useful if the units of data in the file extend over several lines. For instance, if the file contains blocks that always end with a `}` at the end of a line then you can set `$/ = "}\n"`. Then you will get everything up until the next end of block returned, possiibly with embedded newlines.

There are a couple of special values for `$/`. Setting it to an empty string with `$/ = ''` will make Perl return everything up until one or more blank lines in the file. Clearly this is useful only if the data in your file is separated into units with blank lines.

Setting `$/` to `undef` will allow the read to continue right up to the end of file. This is what is meant by *slurping* the file into memory, and is sometimes practical for small files. If it is absolutely necessary it is best done using `local` within the confines of a small code block like

```
my $data = do {
  open my $filehandle, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;
  local $/;
  <$filehandle>;
};
```

Setting `$/` to a *reference to* a numeric value will force the read to stop after a specific number of characters. For instance `$/ = \4096` will make `readline` fetch the next 4KB of data from the file for you (or the rest of the file if there is less than 4KB remaining). This could be used for special purposes like caching your own file reads.

By "Using `$/` in Perl over `split`" I imagine you mean the difference between this and using `split` on the the entire file slurped into a scalar variable. The primary consideration is memory space. If the file is more than a few KB then it is very wasteful to read it all into a Perl variable at once if it isn't completely necessary. Using `$/` and `while` will allow just one record at a time to be read into memory, processed, and discarded when the next record is read.

If you think you need all of the file in an array, so that you can look backwards as well as forwards for instance, you should consider the [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile) module which will make it *appear* as if the entire file is in an array (and even let you modify it) but will actually be paging the data in and out of memory as necessary.

An advantage of using `split` is that it takes a *regualr expression* to identify the places to split the string. This is in contrast to `$/` which may only be set to a simple string. If you need to divide the file up in more complex ways this may be useful.

In general, using `$/` together with `while` is the best way to read a file and should be your first choice unless there is an overriding reason why you need something different. It will prevent extravagant memory usage and also encourage better programming by forcing you to concentrate on a single data record at a time.

Answer (score 3):

From the Perl Doc

> $/ and $\ which are the input and output record separators
>   respectively. They control what defines a "record" when you are
>   reading or writing data.

By default, the separator used is `\n`.
However,

If a file contains,

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, --- consectetuer --- adipiscing elit.
```

Defining `$/ = "---\n";`, will make the separator `---` rather than `\n` and it is read in accordingly. You have "split" the string, at the separator.

**[(Reference)](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/06/18/variables.html)**

Comment: I am agree with you Dark but if I have set this variable then when I ask user input it doesn't let me stop entering the values until I press this variable's value. Why it is related to this?

Comment: Well, as I said, `$/` is the **input** record separator. Perl does not realize the record has ended till it is presented with that token. By default, it is the newline character.

Comment: @PrashantTiwari: Keyboard buffering is nothing to do with the `$/` variable. In normal circumstances when you ask an operating system to read from a keyboard it will return a value only when the `Enter` key is pressed. Perl cannot pass the data to your program until it receives it from the system's input, and it is a coincidence that the default value for `$/` is a newline. If you set it to something else then your program will still wait until `Enter` is pressed, but the characters in the input will be split up differently

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what examples you are talking about, but someone might think that

```
my @lines = split $/, $very_long_string;
```

is similar to slurping a file into an array, as in

```
my @lines = <$FILE>;
```

It is not exactly the same, though, for the first argument of `split` is a regex, while `$/` is interpreted as a string only. For the default value of `$/`, there is no difference, but setting it to e.g. `.` should show the difference.